# how do i access my dexie database from my service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline, dexie

I am making an offline ProgressiveWebApp and i have a populated dexie database in my myDatabase.js file.
From my service worker i want to access this database but when i try db.MijnTable.
The db is not defined occurs.
How do i link or access my database in my service worker?
This has to work offline!

I have tried to link my database file with 
`importScripts('tours/mycompany/js/myDatabase?js');`
but that did not work do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Your service worker needs to import dexie and you should declare your db within the service worker itself or in a script that it will import.

You can also use es6 imports and compile the service worker using webpack but in any case the db instance has to live within the service worker. You can also have another db instance in the DOM that talks to the same DB.

Comment: thank you for the answer 
do you mean import dexie like this "importScripts('https://unpkg.com/dexie@2.0.3/dist/dexie.js');"
or do you mean [link](https://dexie.org/docs/ExportImport/dexie-export-import)
because my database takes A LOT of space and has 1500 files in it. is it possible to export and import that from my saved dexie db ?

Comment: I meant importing dexie using importScripts(). You can also export / import the actual data using the dexie-export-import addon from wither a worker or from the browser. Both environments share the same data.: https://dexie.org/docs/ExportImport/dexie-export-import